# Dynamic Page Title Via PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to set my page title dynamically through PHP. My page title is in a head.php file which is included on every page so doing this individually is not an option.

I wrote the following code and I cannot understand why it is not working:

```
<?php
$currentUrl = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$currentpage = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
if("hoosiermommapcs.com"==$currentUrl) {
 $currentTitle = "Home";
}
else if("/index.php"==$currentpage) {
 $currentTitle = "Home";
}
else if("/dispatch.php"==$currentpage) {
 $currentTitle = "Request Pilot Cars";
}
else if("/invoice.php"==$currentpage) {
 $currentTitle = "Submit Invoice";
}
else if("/gallery.php"==$currentpage) {
 $currentTitle = "Image Gallery";
}
else if("/contact.php"==$currentpage) {
 $currentTitle = "Contact Us";
}
$siteTitle = "Hoosier Momma Pilot Car Services | ";
?>
```

And my page title code is:

```
<title><?php echo($siteTitle . $currentTitle); ?></title>
```

The code works for setting "Home" but not on any of the others. If I go to invoice.php it still says "Home" in the title.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `switch($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]) { }` would be ideal for this.

Comment: Didn't even think of using a switch case function until now. May try that instead. Thanks.

Comment: I removed SOLVED from the title. Accepting an answer automatically marks it as being solved. Either post your own answer, accept the given answer or (flag it to) delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed a line and got it working. Posting as an answer in case others come across this:

I removed:

```
if("hoosiermommapcs.com"==$currentUrl) {
 $currentTitle = "Home";
}
```

and made my code:

```
<?php
$currentpage = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
if("/index.php"==$currentpage) {
 $currentTitle = "Home";
}
else if("/dispatch.php"==$currentpage) {
 $currentTitle = "Request Pilot Cars";
}
else if("/invoice.php"==$currentpage) {
 $currentTitle = "Submit Invoice";
}
else if("/gallery.php"==$currentpage) {
 $currentTitle = "Image Gallery";
}
else if("/contact.php"==$currentpage) {
 $currentTitle = "Contact Us";
}
$siteTitle = "Hoosier Momma Pilot Car Services | ";
?>
```

Title:

```
<title><?php echo($siteTitle . $currentTitle); ?></title>
```

Comment: Do you understand why that fixed it?

Comment: Yes and no. I assume that my original code was matching the URL strictly and since on each page the url was the same, the variable stayed the same as well.

Comment: You were using an `else if`.  So once the URL was matched, none of the other conditions were considered and I assume the URL would have matched for any of the pages.

Comment: @Devon is correct, $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] will always be your hostname, "hoosiermommapcs.com" assuming that is your host, not the full url you are visiting. So it won't matter what page you visit $currentUrl will always be equal to  "hoosiermommapcs.com".

Comment: Yep that's where I messed up.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. `$currentUrl.$currentpage` will contains full hostname and query string, but you only check against query string in your if else
2. Your solution will not likely to work if URL has parameters, for example `/index.php?rel=xxx`. Try to use `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` instead `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: I updated my code using this and it didn't work. I'll update my question with the new code so you can take a look and see if I did it right or not.

Comment: print value of `$currentpage` using `var_dump($currentpage)` and let me know what you get for `invoice.php`

Comment: string(12) "/invoice.php"

Comment: Weird. They are looks the same to me. Try this: `var_dump("/invoice.php"==$currentpage);`

Comment: resulted in bool(true)

Comment: And the part to set the page title is below the if else part?

Comment: Yes it is. A few lines down.

Comment: I got it fixed. I posted my fix as an answer. Thank you for the help. It involved part of your code suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To get just the file by itself, you can use:

```
$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'];
```

This is independent of URL parameters. It also is independent of includes and gets the information you see in the address bar. Here are some results:

```
URL                                     RESULT
http://example.com/index.php            /index.php
http://example.com/about.php?a=dsa      /about.php
http://example.com/t/t.php?t=t          /t/t.php
```

As you can see, this is independent of URL parameters as well. From there, you can do something like:

```
switch( $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] )
{
    default:
        $title = "";
        break;
    case "/index.php":
        $title = "Home";
        break;
    case "/about.php":
        $title = "About";
        break;
}
```

Or you can use a dictionary if the switch/case gets daunting:

```
$file = $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'];
$titleDict = [
    "/index.php" => "Home",
    "/about.php" => "About"
];

if( array_key_exists($file,$titleDict) )
    $title = $titleDict[$file];
else
    $title = "";
```

Comment: Tried it. Replaced $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]; with it and took out the slashes and still no change. Could it be something else?

Comment: If all you did was make that replacement you will not see any results. Look at my updates for the switch/case or dictionary options. Redo the implementation entirely.

Comment: `__FILE__` I believe will return head.php instead of index.php, or other, in this case.